# Apache 2.2 .htaccess File Migration - Regex Error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, apache2.2

We're trying to migrate our .htaccess file to Apache 2.2.25. It appears our .htaccess file is not compatible with our older version to the new version of Apache 2.2.25 due to the changes to regex.

I've done some research, but sadly I was not able to figure out what needs to be changed.

We're receiving the following error in the Apache error log.

> .htaccess: Regular expression could not be compiled.

Here is our .htaccess file. These "RedirectMatch 301" I think are what is causing the problem.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/?$ http://www.domain.com/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/products/?$ http://www.domain.com/products/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/products/about/?$ http://www.domain.com/products/about/
```

The following seem to work fine and do not produce an error in the Apache error log.

```
#Wordpress configuration and force www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.in/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Those are all fine, are you sure it's not something in a container, like `<FilesMatch>`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/products/?$ http://www.domain.com/products/
```

We used this instead. This did not produce an error.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/products/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/products/$1
```